# What processes are in place to manage high performance people in the workplace

Tags: professionalism, work-environment

I am researching different individuals experiences for my degree module  regarding the processes that organizations may have in place for high performance people and their development by effective performance management.

What are examples of performance management systems designed with specific consideration for high-performing individuals?

Comment: Why do you think there is an upper limit?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Tall poppy syndrome tends to come into play.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be "Does any system for performance management exist that really works?". Then you could look at one for high performance people. Australia tried the [AWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_workplace_agreement) but that was a bust.

Answer (score 2):

High performing individuals in organizations tend to be achievement oriented either in a team setting, individual level or in a leadership capacity. It's important to work closely with the individual to:

- Chart out a 1-3-5 year career plan for the individual (to further develop their strengths and acknowledge/manage around. Their weaknesses)
- Expose them to senior leadership on the initiatives they work on to give them feedback from multiple levels
- Establish a senior mentor in the organization that can be a foundation for advice
- Provide 360 feedback to the individual - 1) feedback from who they reported to 2) feedback from who reported to them and 3) feedback from their peer group - often times they will be very good in 2/3 of these vs. 3/3

High performing and high potential individuals are huge leverage points in the organization and can be fantastic athletes to drove the business forward as long as you keep raising the bar and genuinely developm them as long term members of the team.